# How to FILTER for string in numeric column

Tags: sql, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to filter out my Spark DF to only show **text** values in a **numeric** field - as the data is unstructured.

Not quite sure how to work the code below for the scenario above:

```
sparkdf = sparkdf.filter(col("colToFilter") <evaluation>)
```

If I were to try something similar in SQL, I would perform the following:

```
SELECT * FROM tbl
WHERE col NOT LIKE '%[0-9]%'
```

An example of my current table would look like this:

```
|RefId|
|0|
|1|
|1|
|1|
|RefNum2|
|1|
```

I would like to show only "RefNum2" as an output.

I would really appreciate any assistance.

Thank you.

Comment: Could you integrate your post with an example of input/output data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an `rlike` filter as below:

```
df.filter("RefId NOT RLIKE '^[0-9]+$'").show()
+-------+
|  RefId|
+-------+
|RefNum2|
+-------+
```

Or

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F

df.filter(~F.col("RefId").rlike("^[0-9]+$")).show()
+-------+
|  RefId|
+-------+
|RefNum2|
+-------+
```

Answer (score 1):

the simplest request:
select * from tbl1 where col regexp('[a-z]');

Comment: displays everything where there are at least some non-numeric characters of lowercase Latin letters